# Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. } using table, tabular and resizebox

Tags: tables

I've reveiwed all the other threads on this topic and have not been able to figure it out. It must be something I'm completely missing.

I recieved the error above "Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. }"

Here's a full reproducible code snippet

```
\begin{table}[h!]
    \resizebox{5in}{!}{
        \begin{tabular}[h!]{|c||c|c|c|||c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{}{|c||}{Dataset} &
            \multicolumn{3}{c|||}{A} &
            \multicolumn{3}{c|}{B} &  
            \hline


            \bfseries Year & \bfseries parameter & \bfseries gof & \bfseries p-value & \bfseries parameter & \bfseries gof & \bfseries p-value \\
            \hline


1998 & 1.2661         & 0.4046   & 0.57         & 1.2889            & 0.3214      & 0.7             \\ \hline
1999 & 1.2685         & 0.4049   & 0.58         & 1.2913            & 0.3225      & 0.71            \\ \hline
2000 & 1.2681         & 0.4053   & 0.57         & 1.2942            & 0.321       & 0.71            \\ \hline
2001 & 1.2679         & 0.4082   & 0.56         & 1.2896            & 0.3208      & 0.71            \\ \hline
2002 & 1.2666         & 0.4098   & 0.55         & 1.2907            & 0.321       & 0.71            \\ \hline
2003 & 1.2673         & 0.4096   & 0.55         & 1.2849            & 0.3203      & 0.71            \\ \hline
2004 & 1.2678         & 0.409    & 0.57         & 1.2866            & 0.3187      & 0.72            \\ \hline

        \end{tabular}
    }
    \caption[stuff]{morestuff}
    \label{table:all.models}
\end{table}
```

Can anyone see something I'm not seeing?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The instruction `\multicolumn{}{|c||}{Dataset}` generates a syntax error. Did you mean to write `\multicolumn{1}{|c||}{Dataset}`?

Comment: You might alos consider not using `resizebox` in order to make the table occupy a certain space as this approach will lead to inconsistent font sizes and line widths throughout your document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The immediate source of the error message is the line

```
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{B} &
```

It should be

```
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{B} \\
```

Two additional observations:

- `\multicolumn{}{|c||}{Dataset}` isn't correct either. It should be either `\multicolumn{1}{|c||}{Dataset}` or, much more simply, `Dataset`.
- The option `[h!]` in `\begin{tabular}[h!]` is meaningless and simply ignored. Valid options are `t` ("top"), `c` ("center" -- the default), and `b` ("bottom").

---

*Addendum*: If this were *my* table, I would strive hard to give it a much more open "look", mainly by omitting all vertical lines and using fewer, but well spaced, horizontal lines. There's no need for the `\resizebox` "sledge hammer". Use a `tabular*` environment instead. I would also not **bold-face** the header cells, and I'd give more structure to the table's header material, and I'd align the numbers in the numerical columns on their respective decimal markers.

These ideas are implemented in the second table below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\resizebox{5in}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}[h!]{|c||c|c|c||c|c|c|}
\hline
Dataset &
\multicolumn{3}{c||}{A} &
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{B} \\  
\hline
\bfseries Year & \bfseries parameter & 
\bfseries gof & \bfseries p-value & 
\bfseries parameter & \bfseries gof & 
\bfseries p-value \\
\hline
1998 & 1.2661 & 0.4046 & 0.57 & 1.2889 & 0.3214 & 0.7  \\ \hline
1999 & 1.2685 & 0.4049 & 0.58 & 1.2913 & 0.3225 & 0.71 \\ \hline
2000 & 1.2681 & 0.4053 & 0.57 & 1.2942 & 0.321  & 0.71 \\ \hline
2001 & 1.2679 & 0.4082 & 0.56 & 1.2896 & 0.3208 & 0.71 \\ \hline
2002 & 1.2666 & 0.4098 & 0.55 & 1.2907 & 0.321  & 0.71 \\ \hline
2003 & 1.2673 & 0.4096 & 0.55 & 1.2849 & 0.3203 & 0.71 \\ \hline
2004 & 1.2678 & 0.409  & 0.57 & 1.2866 & 0.3187 & 0.72 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}% end of scope of \resizebox instruction
\caption[stuff]{morestuff}
\label{table:all.models}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{5in}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l 
    *{2}{*{2}{S[table-format=1.4]}S[table-format=1.2]} }
\toprule
Year & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Dataset} \\
\cmidrule{2-7}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{B} \\  
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{5-7}
& {Parameter} & {gof} & {p-value} & {Parameter} & {gof} & {p-value} \\
\midrule
1998 & 1.2661 & 0.4046 & 0.57 & 1.2889 & 0.3214 & 0.7  \\ 
1999 & 1.2685 & 0.4049 & 0.58 & 1.2913 & 0.3225 & 0.71 \\ 
2000 & 1.2681 & 0.4053 & 0.57 & 1.2942 & 0.321  & 0.71 \\ 
2001 & 1.2679 & 0.4082 & 0.56 & 1.2896 & 0.3208 & 0.71 \\ 
2002 & 1.2666 & 0.4098 & 0.55 & 1.2907 & 0.321  & 0.71 \\ 
2003 & 1.2673 & 0.4096 & 0.55 & 1.2849 & 0.3203 & 0.71 \\ 
2004 & 1.2678 & 0.409  & 0.57 & 1.2866 & 0.3187 & 0.72 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\caption{A much more ``open'' look}
\label{table:another_look}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Off-topic:

I would design your table on the following way:

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, % for nicer horizontal rules (\toprule, \cmidrule, \midrule,\bottomrule)
            makecell} % for column headers (\thesd)
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\small}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for S column type: numbers are aligned at decimal points

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                         c
                    *{2}{S[table-format=1.4]}
                         S[table-format=1.2]
                    *{2}{S[table-format=1.4]}
                         S[table-format=1.2]
                            }
    \toprule
Dataset & \multicolumn{3}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{B}     \\
    \cmidrule{2-4}\cmidrule{5-7}
\thead{Year}    & {\thead{parameter}} & {\thead{gof}} & {\thead{p-value}}
                & {\thead{parameter}} & {\thead{gof}} & {\thead{p-value}} \\
    \midrule
1998 & 1.2661   & 0.4046   & 0.57   & 1.2889    & 0.3214    & 0.7   \\
1999 & 1.2685   & 0.4049   & 0.58   & 1.2913    & 0.3225    & 0.71  \\
2000 & 1.2681   & 0.4053   & 0.57   & 1.2942    & 0.321     & 0.71  \\
2001 & 1.2679   & 0.4082   & 0.56   & 1.2896    & 0.3208    & 0.71  \\
2002 & 1.2666   & 0.4098   & 0.55   & 1.2907    & 0.321     & 0.71  \\
2003 & 1.2673   & 0.4096   & 0.55   & 1.2849    & 0.3203    & 0.71  \\
2004 & 1.2678   & 0.409    & 0.57   & 1.2866    & 0.3187    & 0.72  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\caption[stuff]{morestuff}
\label{table:all.models}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks clean! Thank you. I'll use it!

Comment: @Joseph, I'm glad to help you. Of course, you can up-vote answer  if you liked it  ;-)